# sql where clause but not for some records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table where I store some items with prices and others items without prices.

I want to select all the items with price but in the otherhand I want to select some items without prices at the same time. Is there any choice to do this?

Right now I have this select statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT  idItem, itemDescription, price
FROM    myTable
WHERE   price > 0 and   idItem = '000228'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select all items with price > 0 plus the ine with id 000228, the where clause needs to be "price > 0 OR idItem = '000228'"

Answer (score 3):

Try to add `price is null` condition as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT  idItem, itemDescription, price
FROM    myTable
WHERE   (price > 0 or price is null) and   idItem = '000228'
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to select item 000228 as well...

```
WHERE ISNULL(price,1) > 0 and IdItem = '000228'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT DISTINCT idItem, itemDescription, price
FROM myTable
WHERE ISNULL(price, 0) > 0
    AND idItem = '000228'
```